# How to make anonymous access to SMB external storage in NextCloud?

Tags: nextcloud

I'm trying to enable external SMB external storage in Nextcloud (where the SMB mount does not require a password).

Documentation says that there is a "None authentication" but I don't see such option

https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/admin_manual/configuration_files/external_storage/auth_mechanisms.html

I tried different options, but they all send credentials, no anonymous option.

Is that possible to make anonymous external storage?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It was difficult to understand what you are asking.  I've made significant changes to the question to hopefully convey what you are trying to ask.  Please check and correct/roll-back and add more details if I got it wrong.